# How to declare a pointer to a template function in D lang?

Tags: templates, function-pointers, d

I'm playing with some D code.
I have some functions filtering on a array:

```
auto Case1Filters(R)(R lines) if(isInputRange!R) { ... }
auto Case2Filters(R)(R lines) if(isInputRange!R) { ... }
```

I want to have a function pointer and assign to it one of my filters, so I declared a variable like this:

```
    auto function(R)(R lines) filter = null;
```

And I get these error when compiling:

```
conv.d(54): Error: basic type expected, not function
conv.d(54): Error: function declaration without return type. (Note that constructors are always named 'this')
conv.d(54): Error: no identifier for declarator int function(R)(R lines)
conv.d(54): Error: semicolon expected following function declaration
```

It looks like the compiler thinks that I'm declaring a function.
I tried with an alias, too, but to no avail: is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have any type of dynamic dispatch to a template, for the same reason you can't have a virtual template function.

Despite all appearances D is a statically typed language which means that all function pointer declarations must have all types available (including the return type `auto` can only be used when the body is included).

So if R is already declared then you can do:

```
auto foo(R)(){//R is defined here as some type

    Ret function(R lines) filter = null;//no template param when declaring the function pointer and concrete return type

    filter = &Case1Filters!R;

    filter(r);

}
```

Comment: It does solve the problem :-), albeit I was expecting that the compiler would have been able to deduce the return type, both the functions being present and returning an array of string.

Comment: but the function could be assigned a third unrelated function with the same signature but different return type

Comment: It could, but it doesn't: my expectation would be that if the compiler finds two mismatching functions it chokes (a bit like in this case: http://pastebin.com/8Tf5TdPQ) But maybe I'm just missing something: I'm super new to the language.

Comment: just with `auto function(R lines) filter=null;` the compiler can't know which functions you want to assign to it (it could be anything from `bool foo(R r){return false;}` to `bool bar(R r){return "some string;}`), both could be valid if no return type is set

Comment: yes I understand the reason of the error. I was just wondering if, given the fact that all the assignments are known, the compiler could not track down each assignment, verify the return type, and complain if it's not consistent. Clearly it does not. Thanks a lot for the explanation, though :)